# tkinter entry allows blank submissions and having to manually erase

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay so the script runs where you type a entry press submit and a pop-up window shows what was typed. I have two issues I'd like help figuring out. Blank submissions and clearing the text after hitting submit.

Blank submission: input1: hello   input2: world input3: "nothing typed" input4:hello world
I get a blank line on input 3 but I don't want anything to happen(no error message needed)
I tried to add .strip() but that didn't work / I didn't put it in correctly I tried it on the end of line 13 `name=entry.get().strip` and I tried adding a line  `entry.strip()`

Clearing text: input1: welcome   input2: to   input3:python
I have to manually erase the text inputs for the entry widget before I can type the next line

```
import tkinter as tk

flag = False
win=""

def setflag(event):
    global flag
    flag = False
    
#function that prints the entry
def entry_function(e=None):
    global flag,win
    name = entry.get()
    if not flag:
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        win.geometry('100x100')
        win.bind('<Destroy>', setflag)
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
        flag = True
        win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 300))
    else:
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
     

 #Setup for the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.bind('<Return>', entry_function)
x = window.winfo_x()
y = window.winfo_y()

#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Manual:", bg = "dark grey", fg = "white")
entry = tk.Entry(window)
button = tk.Button(window,text = "submit",
                   command = entry_function)

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes to the code (explanation in code comments):

```py
import tkinter as tk


# no need to use flag because just change win to None
# and check if it is None rather than using an 
# additional variable
win = None


# this would set win variable to None
def set_win_none(event=None):
    global win
    win = None


def entry_function(event=None):
    global win
    name = entry.get()
    
    # check if the string is empty, if so
    # stop the function
    if not name:
        return
    # clear the entry
    entry.delete('0', 'end')
    
    # as mentioned win can be used, it just shortens the code
    if win is None:
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        # set geometry as needed, this
        # will place the window
        # on the right of the main window
        win.geometry(f'100x100+{window.winfo_x() + window.winfo_width()}+{window.winfo_y()}')
        win.bind('<Destroy>', set_win_none)
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()
    else:
        tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()


window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, text="Manual:", bg="dark grey", fg="white")
entry = tk.Entry(window)
button = tk.Button(window, text="submit", command=entry_function)

# better bind the return key to the entry since it is
# directly involved
entry.bind('<Return>', entry_function)

# very rarely do you need to use .place
# better use .grid or .pack
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)

window.mainloop()
```

There is rarely a need to use `.place`, better use `.grid` or `.pack` method for placing widgets, they are far more dynamic and adjust to how the window changes.

Also:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: I appreciate the edits, this was  definitely a post I was going to get around to(checking to see if my coding was.. "meta" ) as I'm learning 100% on the fly from a wide range of resources. I'll definitely start reading over the edits and the pep 8 link. I've already seen you once or twice before so I'm excited you've seen my code growing and can contribute this sort of information!